# Как работать в OpenGL с буфером глубины glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

Как сделать что бы один объект перекрывал другой... Тот объект который в цикле был последний рисуется сверху. А как сделать что бы рисовался сверху тот у которого больше значение z?
В моем коде с буфером глубины один из объектов вовсе исчезает... А что бы было перекрытие! как это сделать?

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

    glfwPollEvents();

    
    
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 1);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, quads1);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    

    
    glColor4f(0, 1, 0, 1);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, quads2);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    
    

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```

[image: без буфера]

[image: с буфером]

Comment: Вероятно дело в координатах треугольника и камеры. Попробуйте отдалить камеру.

Comment: [3:15](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lG75rBTcesk) - теоретически почему вы не можете видеть треугольник. Особенно обратите внимание на область видимости.

Comment: Извиняюсь, камера отдаляется в glViewport ?

Comment: Тоже извиняюсь, в opengl очень недавно и только в смешке с SFML. Ответа дать не могу.

Comment: Спасибо я разобрался) действительно дело было в области видимости